Canonical question for tracing IP address of transactions
Maybe it's just me, but I've noticed a several recent questions regarding trying to find the originating IP address of a transaction or Bitcoin address.  Perhaps this is due to the proliferation of ransomware, or perhaps some other factor.
Either way, it seems we should have a canonical question for Bitcoin's relationship to IP addresses.  Ideally, the answers would cover everything from how block explorers attempt to determine IP address, to running a node on TOR.
Do we already have a question like this, and if not, is there interest in creating one?

Great idea. I don't know one from the top of my mind, but if you can't find one, I can look later.
